# Is it possible to combine "super" and "slightly" to mean something smaller than slightly?

Tags: adjectives

For example : "She looks super slightly similar." would mean she looks a really small bit similar.
From a french background, we allow ourselves to combine certain superlatives in this way, but I cannot find anywhere with such usage in english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ever+so+slightly%2Csuper+slightly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cever%20so%20slightly%3B%2Cc0) strongly suggest that 'super slightly' is non-idiomatic, with which indication I'd agree. We'd use

> She looks ever-so-slightly taller.

[Hyphens optional IMO] [and I've switched to the 'taller' example]

(57 000 Google hits for "ever so slightly taller"; 7 dubious hits for "super slightly taller")

From [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/ever_so)

> *ever so* (phrase)
>
> Very.
>
> ‘I am ever so grateful’)

[no hyphens when used predicatively]

And an adverb-modifying example from [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ever-so):

> I saw him pause ever so slightly.

Comment: We also use *very* as in "*very slightly taller*".